# Simple voice chat over command line?

Tags: sound, programming, microphone, ubuntu-sdk, p2p

I will be using this for development.

**What I want is:**

- No large proprietary blob overhead to accomplish this, like skype
- No account needed. So no skype account, no email, etc etc.
- Ability to run without a gui.
- Ability for multiple users to connect to easily.

This will be used in a pair programming project I am creating, **so what the program would look like is this:**

1. Start program
2. Host pair programming session.
3. Would you like to enable voice chat?
4. Yes -> Wait for user's to connect to session.
5. Remote User: Input address to connect to session. Prompt: Voice Chat is enabled. A) **Do you wish to listen?** B) **Do you wish to enable your microphone?**

a) Yes -> Speakers will now output other user's mic input until session is ended.

b) Yes -> Other user can now here you on your mic if it is enabled.

The goal is to avoid having the user to avoid inputting any other information than he already has.

Comment: Did you look at linphone? what about this? https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/voice_chat